# SQLite with encryption/password protection

Tags: encryption, sqlite, password-protection

I'm just learning to use SQLite and I was curious if such is possible:

1. Encryption of the database file?
2. Password protect opening of the database?

PS. I know that there is this "SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE).", but according to the documentation, "The SEE is licensed software...." and "The cost of a perpetual source code license for SEE is US $2000."

Comment: It's certainly possible and there exist several open source solutions besides SEE. Among them the encryption extension coming with wxSQLite3. [See my answer to a similar question for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971483/how-to-compile-wxsqlite3-and-sqlite-to-get-encryption-support/4979051#4979051)

Comment: @RobotMess: To be honest with you -- none of the ones listed here. I had strict time constrains on that project, so I had to do something quick. I went with what I knew best -- AES on the raw data before placing it into the DB... It is not very efficient though in terms of lookup, search and DB management.

Comment: @ahmd0 Hm, doesn't that make the DB kind of useless though? I mean, all it really does now is ensure commits are atomic.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If targeting .Net Standard 4.6.1+ or Core, I think a fairly straightforward to get Sqlite encryption is to use Microsoft.Data.Sqlite per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49588874/8663165).

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Here are a few implementations:

- [SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE)](https://sqlite.org/com/see.html) - The official implementation (commercial)
- [SQLite3 Multiple Ciphers](https://github.com/utelle/SQLite3MultipleCiphers) - An encryption extension for SQLite with support for multiple ciphers (open source, [documentation here](https://utelle.github.io/SQLite3MultipleCiphers))
- [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher) - Uses openSSL's libcrypto to implement encryption (commercial, open source version available [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher))
- [SQLiteCrypt](https://sqlite-crypt.com) - Custom implementation, modified API (commercial)

Comment: botansqlite3 is now distributed independantly of Botan.

Comment: There is also [litereplica](http://litereplica.io/sqlite-encryption.html). It uses the ChaCha cipher, faster than AES on portable devices based on ARMv7

Comment: SQLite3 .Net as built in support for encryption now, which largely invalidates this answer.

Comment: @Krythic The fact that .Net library having encryption support does not "largely invalidate" this answer in any possible way even though the library carries native SQLite3. This answer is still relevant to this day.

Answer (score 22):

**NOTE: This answer is outdated.** The CryptoAPI codec of System.Data.SQLite is an unsupported legacy. See [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/support.wiki).

---

The .NET library [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org) can password protect an SQLite3 DB.
For the first time before doing any operations, set password as follows.

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
conn.SetPassword("password");
conn.open();
```

then next time you can access it like

```
conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;Password=password;");
conn.Open();
```

This wont allow any GUI editor to view Your data.
Later if you wish to change the password, use `conn.ChangePassword("new_password");`
To reset or remove password, use `conn.ChangePassword(String.Empty);`

Comment: Won't work with the open source Sqlite.  No clue what language implementation, language, or API this is supposed to be.

Comment: How do I know which encryption way ``ChangePassword`` used? AES 128? RSA ..?

Comment: RSA 1024 or 2048?  Is there any document could see that more details?

Comment: Get the docs from here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: In my own testing, I've found that the `SetPassword` method (at this time) appears basically useless. The only way I was able to get the `System.Data.SQLite` library to properly apply the password was using the `ChangePassword` method. Using `SetPassword` (*before* calling the `Open` method, as is apparently required by the library), I was still able to open and edit the DB in SQLiteStudio without any password. It wasn't until I used the `ChangePassword` method (***after*** calling the `Open` method) that the password application actually "stuck".

Comment: SetPassword not exists in SQLiteConnection object, System.Data.SQLite 1.0.113.0

Answer (score 16):

**NOTE: This answer is outdated.** The CryptoAPI codec of System.Data.SQLite is an unsupported legacy. See [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/support.wiki).

---

The .net library [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) also provides for encryption.

Comment: ASP.NET != SQL Server != installed instance of SQL Server

Comment: But [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) is not from Microsoft. This question is not about .Net but if it were then other compatibilities and incompatibilities would be important.

Answer (score 10):

**NOTE: This answer is outdated.** The CryptoAPI codec of System.Data.SQLite is an unsupported legacy. See [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/support.wiki).

---

You can get **`sqlite3.dll`** file with encryption support from http://system.data.sqlite.org/.

1 - Go to http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki and download one of the packages.  .NET version is irrelevant here.

2 - Extract `SQLite.Interop.dll` from package and rename it to `sqlite3.dll`. This DLL supports encryption via plaintext passwords or encryption keys.

The mentioned file is native and does *NOT* require .NET framework. It might need Visual C++ Runtime depending on the package you have downloaded.

This is the package that I've downloaded for 32-bit development: http://system.data.sqlite.org/blobs/1.0.94.0/sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-Win32-2010-1.0.94.0.zip

Comment: In my particular example I needed a `.lib` that I could embed into my executable. I couldn't have any dlls.

Comment: Please also check this one https://github.com/rindeal/wxSQLite3-VS which will give you a `lib` and `dll` file.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, the following is not intended to be a substitute for a proper security solution.

After playing around with this for four days, I've put together a solution using only the open source System.Data.SQLite package from NuGet. I don't know how much protection this provides. I'm only using it for my own course of study. This will create the DB, encrypt it, create a table, and add data.

```
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace EncryptDB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = @"C:\Programming\sqlite3\db.db";
            string passwordString = "password";
            byte[] passwordBytes = GetBytes(passwordString);
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(connectionString);
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + connectionString + ";Version=3;");
            conn.SetPassword(passwordBytes);
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE data(filename TEXT, filepath TEXT, filelength INTEGER, directory TEXT)", conn);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO data VALUES('name', 'path', 200, 'dir')", conn);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
            return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Optionally, you can remove `conn.SetPassword(passwordBytes);`, and replace it with `conn.ChangePassword("password");` which needs to be placed after `conn.Open();` instead of before. Then you won't need the GetBytes method.

To decrypt, it's just a matter of putting the password in your connection string before the call to open.

```
        string filename = @"C:\Programming\sqlite3\db.db";
        string passwordString = "password";
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;Password=" + passwordString + ";");
        conn.Open();
```

Comment: `"I think I saw 128 bit somewhere"` - this is a very bad statement if you're planning to deal with encryption. The rule of thumb is that you **never** do it yourself if you don't understand it. Otherwise you'd be better off not using it at all.

Comment: SetPassword not exists in SQLiteConnection object, System.Data.SQLite 1.0.113.0

Comment: This answer require a SEE licence: 
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.SEE.License, Version=1.0.118.0"

Answer (score 2):

Well, `SEE` is expensive. However `SQLite` has interface built-in for encryption (Pager). This means, that on top of existing code one can easily develop some encryption mechanism, does not have to be `AES`. Anything really.
Please see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49161716/9418360

You need to define SQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 to enable Pager encryption. Sample code below (original `SQLite` source):

```
#ifdef SQLITE_HAS_CODEC
/*
** This function is called by the wal module when writing page content
** into the log file.
**
** This function returns a pointer to a buffer containing the encrypted
** page content. If a malloc fails, this function may return NULL.
*/
SQLITE_PRIVATE void *sqlite3PagerCodec(PgHdr *pPg){
  void *aData = 0;
  CODEC2(pPg->pPager, pPg->pData, pPg->pgno, 6, return 0, aData);
  return aData;
}
#endif
```

There is a commercial version in `C language` for `SQLite` encryption using AES256 - it can also work with `PHP`, but it needs to be compiled with `PHP` and `SQLite` extension. It de/encrypts `SQLite` database file on the fly, file contents are always encrypted. Very useful.

http://www.iqx7.com/products/sqlite-encryption

Answer (score 2):

I had also similar problem. Needed to store sensitive data in simple database (SQLite was the perfect choice except security). Finally I have placed database file on TrueCrypt encrypted valume.

Additional console app mounts temporary drive using TrueCrypt CLI and then starts the database application. Waits until the database application exits and then dismounts the drive again.

Maybe not suitable solution in all scenarios but for me working well ...

Answer (score 1):

You can always encrypt data on the client side. Please note that not all of the data have to be encrypted because it has a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLite's function creation routines ([PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php)):

```
$db_obj->sqliteCreateFunction('Encrypt', 'MyEncryptFunction', 2);
$db_obj->sqliteCreateFunction('Decrypt', 'MyDecryptFunction', 2);
```

When inserting data, you can use the encryption function directly and INSERT the encrypted data or you can use the custom function and pass unencrypted data:

```
$insert_obj = $db_obj->prepare('INSERT INTO table (Clear, Encrypted) ' .
 'VALUES (:clear, Encrypt(:data, "' . $passwordhash_str . '"))');
```

When retrieving data, you can also use SQL search functionality:

```
$select_obj = $db_obj->prepare('SELECT Clear, ' .
 'Decrypt(Encrypted, "' . $passwordhash_str . '") AS PlainText FROM table ' .
 'WHERE PlainText LIKE :searchterm');
```