# How do I examine a SQLite database pulled off of the Android emulator, it seems to be password protected

Tags: android, database, sqlite, password-protection

I read [this article](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) and wrote simple class using this topic. After the database was succesfully created and updated, I pulled it out from emulator.

To check the content of the database I used SQliteManger. When I try to open the file, SQliteManger asked for a password. I have the following questions:

1. Does this mean that DB is protected by password and only root can read it?
2. How can I change the password?
3. How is this password generated?

Comment: Checkout this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to password protect the SQLite database itself. What you can do on the contrary is to encrypt the whole DB file using a key. Later when you access the database, decrypt the database first and execute your query on the decrypted database.

> Does this mean that DB is protected by password and only root can read
>   it?

No, this is not possible. When you `adb pull` a file, it is downloaded and saved on the disk as your own user.

> How can I change the password? 
>   How is this password generated?

It's hard to answer without looking at the database you are dealing with and the program you are using (SQLiteManager) to access the database to answer why and where you are getting the password prompt from. Try to upload and share them if you like for better answers. In the mean time, you can try [SQLite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) which is freely available on SourceForge and has always worked for me.

P.S.
[The article](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) you point at suggests to use the [same program](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) I suggested above. So, give it a shot. Also, the article does not seem to talk about encrypting the database anywhere. So, you don't need to fret about finding the database password.