# Alternative for SQLite, with protection

Tags: c#, wpf, database, security, sqlite

I am using atm a SQLite database that I give to users who use my (wpf c#) application however I didn t find any good tutorial or guide how to secure my sqlite databasefile. I am very happy that SQLite is very small my database file is only 10KB. But if people have a tool like sqlitebrowser to open sqlite databases then they can just view the data and edit it! Anyone knows a good alternative(or if you know a good place where they explain how I can secure my SQLite database and also be able to hide the SQLite connectionstring in the application)

Comment: How much protection do you need? If you need 100% protection, there is little you can do besides putting the database on a remote server under your control, or shipping a SWAT team along your product.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite with encryption/password protection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection)

Comment: lol @ SWAT :D. Anyway the users will edit the database with the application, and it must be usable offline.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876).  It's free - not sure about encryption.

Comment: Oke I ll have a look at it. If I don t have to alter too much code or anything and it is not too hard to install in my app. If this works I ll report back here. btw any disadvantages that you might know?

Comment: SHA-2 is a family of hashing algorithms, not an encryption algorithm.

Comment: Whoops, just quoting direct from MS's web page.