# Implementing SQL AES ENCRYPTION into SQLite using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, aes

is it possible to implement SQL AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT into SQLite using PHP ?
For example I have a PHP Code:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO parent (Request, Column1, Column2) VALUES ('$Request',AES_ENCRYPT('$Col1','$key'),AES_ENCRYPT('$Col2','$key'))";
```

and this query works in SQL, but is it possible to use this same query in SQLite?

Comment: You meant "This query works in MySQL". SQLite doesn't have built-in AES encryption functions, so you'll have to send in encrypted data.

Comment: Yes this query works in MySQL. So I cant use this AES_ENCRYPT in SQLite ?

Comment: So how can I use AES for SQLite ?

Comment: Encrypt and decrypt data on the PHP end. Store the encrypted data in an SQLite BLOB.

Comment: Look at SQLCipher - it might be what you actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have 2 options :

- encrypt your values at the PHP level and store them as BLOBs or base64 strings
- encrypt the whole database executing the following command (just like any other regular SQL command) : **PRAGMA hexkey='0x_your_key_in_hex_format'** . Don't forget do do the same when you open your database for running SELECT queries. [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki) is the official documentation.

Comment: I have made a PHP AEE encryption amd it works but I need to use AES as SQL query so thanks for the reply I will try SQLite Encryption Extension and I will come back if I have any problems.

Comment: Hi mbarthelemy, do you have any example on how to use this PRAGMA in PHP for sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

Well, about 10 minutes ago I finished installing `PHP 7.2.2` on my HP laptop with `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit`. You do not need to acquire a license for `SQLite` Encryption Extension (SEE). On top of existing `PHP` extension I have added a few `C` files with `AES` and `SQLite` functions for en/decrypting Pager. It works well and now I will try to make it work using Intel i5 built-in AES functionality - to get the best out of hardware itself.
Now, to open a sqlite db I can use the following:

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
      function __construct(){
        $this->open('sqlite3.db',SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE, 'your_password_here');
      }
}
```

Encrypting the whole database is definitely the best solution.
Write me a message for details. I will probably publish this solution soon.

Comment: hi. When I use it it says file is not a database. any idea ?