# sqlite3 PDO error

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I am trying to open an encrypted sqlite3 database using PDO (PHP 7.1.1).

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.sqlite','','password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$results = $db->query('SELECT * from Table');
```

The above code throws following exception:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 26 file is encrypted or is not a database
```

Is my connection string correct?
Is it possible to open an encrypted sqlite3 database using PDO?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite3 database encryption -- determining encryption library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514007/sqlite3-database-encryption-determining-encryption-library)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the [PDO SQLite interface](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) makes no mention of encryption, nor does the documentation for the [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).  The only thing I'm aware of is the [SQLite3 class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) which has a parameter for an encryption key in [the constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.construct.php).

Per the documentation:

> **encryption_key** - An optional encryption key used when encrypting and decrypting an SQLite database. ***If the SQLite encryption module is not installed, this parameter will have no effect***.

As mentioned in the comments on your question, there are other answers which address installing and getting a sqlite encryption module working with PHP.