# System.Data.SQLite Encryption C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, encryption, system.data.sqlite

I am currently trying to find a good documentation for encrypting an SQLite DB through a C++ program and I am struggling to find a good documentation on the net since most links seem to be broken.

I came across this: http://sqlite-crypt.com/documentation.htm - which seems to be OK but I cannot figure out how to use the dll's provided by system.data.sqlite as they do not have a .lib file.

So my question sums up to two things:

1. Does anyone have a good documentation\example of SQLite encryption with C++?
2. If the link I posted above is valid - does anyone know how to actually use it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5877130/477878 seems to link a few (untested by me) implementations.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimIsaksson, although this question doesn't give to much insight on using system.data.sqlite with c++.

Comment: Are you using managed C++ on Windows/Windows RT/...?

Comment: I suspect System.Data.Sqlite is a managed DLL and can't (easily) be used from unmanaged C++.

Comment: Alright, so can you explain how to use it lets say with a managed C++ code?