# SQLite PCL async with encryption/password protection

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I am developing an uwp application , and using sqlite async PCL , and i need to encrypt my database file , i already saw this link 
[SQLite with encryption/password protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection)
but i can't migrate to those libraries ,i need a solution within SQLite.Net.Async PCL

Comment: can you describe the problem why you "but i can't migrate to those libraries" ?

Comment: The sqlite can be set password

Comment: i'm actually using  sqlite.net pcl async (sqliteasyncconnection ) so i need a solution within this library

Comment: @lindexi  SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
conn.SetPassword("password");
conn.open(); ======> SQLiteAsyncConnection doesn't support a method like setPassword

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library (i.e. this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl))? If so, check out [this sample](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89394/sqlite-net-pcl-with-sqlitepclraw-bundle-sqlcipher).