# Password protect sqlite3 database with python

Tags: python, sqlite, passwords

Is it possible to password protect a database using sqlite3 with python? I found another thread but it didn't help since the language and implementation was different.

The link I found was: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24349362

Thanks