# Compile System.Data.Sqlite With AES256

Tags: encryption, build, sqlite, msbuild, system.data.sqlite

I'm knee deep in compilation for sqlite, system.data.sqlite, and xerial's JDBC trying to get an encrypted sqlite file working through all three. From my understanding, *system.data.sqlite* uses RC4 encryption, and SQLCipher/Rijndael/wxSqlite can use AES256.

[Using this library](https://github.com/rindeal/SQLite3-Encryption), one can easily compile Windows binaries for AES256 encryption.
[This library](https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt) offers [Xerial's JDBC](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) by incorporating [wxsqlite3's improvements](https://github.com/utelle/wxsqlite3), which it looks like is actually based on the above (Rijndael's) library.

Because the above two libraries are close to one-and-the-same, and use the same encryption, they have been compatible. I have a working Java project with the encryption-supporting JDBC, and I have a compiled sqlite3.dll and sqlite3shell.exe that allows me to use the command line to encrypt, read, write, etc databases. This sqlite dll and shell are compatible with the databases created with the JDBC.

Where I'm a bit lost is getting [system.data.sqlite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) working with AES256. I need to use this library as it affords me the ability to use Entity Framework and LINQ. I had thought it would not be such an arduous task, but I've been ramming my head into a wall for the past few days on this issue. I have the encryption-ready sqlite3 dll, how do I merge this in with system.data.sqlite?

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 3):

If you're targeting .NET standard 4.6.1+ or Core, you may want to give Microsoft.Data.Sqlite a try. This can give you AES256 encryption by simply adding 2 Nuget Packages. By the way, there are paid options to get AES256 compiled System.Data.Sqlite. Some are listed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877130/8663165).

If your project is currently using System.Data.Sqlite, then transitioning will involve some search/replace of method & class names, much of which is a difference in caps. For example, "SQLiteDataReader" becomes "SqliteDataReader."

Another difference is that Microsoft.Data.Sqlite is strict about column naming. For example, a command that references a column named "DateListed" will fail if the database schema has that column as "Datelisted."

If you want to explore making a transition install 2 nuget packages:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core
Install-Package SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher
```

Setup [SQLitePCL](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw)

```
SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_sqlcipher());
SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();
SQLitePCL.raw.FreezeProvider();
```

Create encrypted database

```
string error = string.Empty;
static SQLitePCL.sqlite3 sqlite
SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_open(dbPath, out sqlite);
SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_exec(sqlite, "PRAGMA key ='myPassword'", out error);
SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_close(sqlite);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I ended up successfully compiling SQLite with an AES256 encryption with some help from the wxsqlite github and its wonderful product owner. The sqlite I've compiled successfully exposes interfaces both to C# and Java so I can interface with both applications.

Comment: @Stephen, would you be kind enough to share your compiled SQLite dll with a sample code? I have been struggling with the same issue. I have managed to get SQLite and SQLCipher working in .net core mvc but have not had luck with .net framework 4.x