# How to protect my sqllitedb3 data from end user manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, encryption

I am using SqlLiteDb3 and SQLite  dll  for my windows application,
Now i need to protect my data from end user by  password protecting or db encrypting and decryption .
How can i do this..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite with encryption/password protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection)

Comment: Well, since the password is stored in the application, It'll be cracked soon or later. These things like cat and mouse game. Nothing will be safe forever. By decompiling your application, he'll get the password easily and read the whole database. So what will the password do in this case ? Nothing.

Comment: @bommelding It's not safe since the password of the database stored in the application. So decompiling the app will give the password. Then it becomes just like a database without a password :)

Comment: How do you know where the password is stored? The OP didn't say.