# System.Data.SQLite What Type/Level of Password Encryption is used

Tags: encryption, sqlite, password-protection

When using the library `System.Data.SQLite` to password protect your SQLite Database what type/level of encryption is used?

When researching SQLite encryption there are many options however when creating a SQLite Database from within a .NET application using the above mentioned library what method of encryption does it use?

To encrypt a SQLite Database all that is required within the .NET code is to simply provide a password within the connection string.

> **SQLite Connection String**
>
> Data Source= [DBFile.sqlite] ;Version=3;Password= [Password];datetimeformat=CurrentCulture;

If the route of encrypting a  SQLite file above is implemented what type of encryption was applied?  I have been unable to locate any documentation that spells this out.

> **Encryption Options:**
>
> I did locate the below link however it does not tell me what I need to
> know.  Unless I'm dense and am missing it.
>
> https://www.bricelam.net/2016/06/13/sqlite-encryption.html
>
> **Stackoverflow Post:**
>
> This SO Post here is outdated as it is pre SQLite 3 however it does
> have some nice documentation on encryption possibilities.  One of the answers in this post
> an individual states that the post is outdated by saying "SQLite3 .Net
> as built in support for encryption now, which largely invalidates this
> answer"
>
> What is the built in encryption mentioned above?
>
> [SQLite with encryption/password protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look through the CHM documentation on [the home page](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki). It barely mentions the encryption. The only info I could find was in the version history, which says this:

> ## 1.0.24.3 beta - January 10, 2006
>
> ...
>
> - Added support for database encryption at the pager level.  Databases are encrypted using a **128-bit RC4 stream algorithm**.  To open an existing encrypted database, you may now specify a "Password={password}" text in the ConnectionString, or you may call the SQLiteConnection.SetPassword() function to set the password on an open connection.  To encrypt existing non-encrypted databases or to change the password on an encrypted database, you must use the SQLiteConnection.ChangePassword() function.  If you use SetPassword() instead of specifying a password in the connection string, or call ChangePassword() you may use a binary byte array or a text string as the password.
>
> ...

(emphasis mine)

A quick glance at the [RC4 Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) reveals that "multiple vulnerabilities have been discovered in RC4, rendering it insecure." I wouldn't trust it.

Also worth noting: the encryption module you're talking about is not a feature of SQLite, but rather an extension that the System.Data.SQLite library provides. Using it will make your database inoperable with other SQLite readers.