# Opening encrypted database with qtsql

Tags: c++, encryption, qtsql

I would like to know if it is possible without adding new libraries, to open an encrypted sql database inside a software using QT libraries.
In the program SQLITEManager, it is possible to use 4 kinds of encryption:

- AES128
- AES256
- RC4
- SQLCipher

My database is accessed with the following code:

```
    QSqlDatabase myDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "UserConnection");
    myDB.setDatabaseName("Files/Users.db");
    if (!myDB.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Failed to open SQL database of registered users";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"Successfully opening SQL database of registered users";
        QSqlQuery query(myDB);
        //actions read or write
    }
```

Is there a way to read the database if I add an encryption from SQLITEManager?

Comment: There's [no standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877130/14637) to encrypt an SQLite database, so you'll likely have to do the legwork yourself.

Comment: So maybe it is better to store it in a binary file