# Why isn't SQLite giving me an error when I try to open a file with the wrong encryption key?

Tags: php, sqlite

I was unable to find any information about this behavior online, so any help will be much appreciated.

When using the following code:

```
//create file with encryption key "test1"
$tempDB = new \SQLite3("temp.db", SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE, "test1");

//attempt to open the same file using key "test2"
$tempDB = new \SQLite3("temp.db", SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE, "test2"); 

var_dump($tempDB->lastErrorCode()); //int(0)  : no error?
```

Is this the expected behavior? If so, how can I check whether or not a key is correct for a given SQLite3 file?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5669905/798677

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite with encryption/password protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'm an idiot. After skimming through [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php) I assumed that encryption was a module that PHP+SQLite ships with or which you can just easily install and use.

Turns out that's not the case. You have to [pay USD 2000](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) in order to use this module. Ugh.

My code was just ignoring the parameter as per [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php):

> An optional encryption key used when encrypting and decrypting an SQLite database. If the SQLite encryption module is not installed, this parameter will have no effect.

Comment: There are various modules. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877130/798677